# Extract value from list inside JSON dictionary (Python)

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I need to extract a value from a dictionary, inside a list, inside a dictionary.
The value I'm tryng to get is `dealId` inside `affectedDeals`.  (highlighted with ^)

```
data = {'date': '2022-11-04T12:36:57.016', 'status': 'OPEN', 'reason': 'SUCCESS', 'dealStatus': 'ACCEPTED', 'epic': 'SILVER', 'dealReference': 'o_0bc30104-8ddf-4d67-9daa-e7d878a8cad9', 'dealId': '006011e7-0055-311e-0000-000080507631', 'affectedDeals': [{'dealId': '006011e7-0055-311e-0000-000080507633', 'status': 'OPENED'}], 'level': 20.138, 'size': 1.0, 'direction': 'BUY', 'guaranteedStop': False, 'trailingStop': False}                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ^
output = 006011e7-0055-311e-0000-000080507633
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

May be this could help you to get the output as expected in question

**Code:**

```
data = {
    "date": "2022-11-04T12:36:57.016",
    "status": "OPEN",
    "reason": "SUCCESS",
    "dealStatus": "ACCEPTED",
    "epic": "SILVER",
    "dealReference": "o_0bc30104-8ddf-4d67-9daa-e7d878a8cad9",
    "dealId": "006011e7-0055-311e-0000-000080507631",
    "affectedDeals": [
        {"dealId": "006011e7-0055-311e-0000-000080507633", "status": "OPENED"}
    ],
    "level": 20.138,
    "size": 1.0,
    "direction": "BUY",
    "guaranteedStop": False,
    "trailingStop": False,
}

[i.get("dealId") for i in data.get("affectedDeals")]
```

**Output :**

```
006011e7-0055-311e-0000-000080507633
```

**Output will be enclosed in list you can use indexing to retrieve the data from list like below**

```
lst = [i.get("dealId") for i in data.get("affectedDeals")]
lst[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```py
data = {'date': '2022-11-04T12:36:57.016', 
        'status': 'OPEN',
        'reason': 'SUCCESS',
        'dealStatus': 'ACCEPTED',
        'epic': 'SILVER',
        'dealReference': 'o_0bc30104-8ddf-4d67-9daa-e7d878a8cad9',
        'dealId': '006011e7-0055-311e-0000-000080507631',
        'affectedDeals': [
            {'dealId': '006011e7-0055-311e-0000-000080507633',
             'status': 'OPENED'
            }
        ],
        'level': 20.138,
        'size': 1.0,
        'direction': 'BUY',
        'guaranteedStop': False,
        'trailingStop': False
        }                                                                                                                                                                                            

print(data['affectedDeals'][0]['dealId'])

# Output: 006011e7-0055-311e-0000-000080507633
```

We basically accessed the list(affectedDeals) and then selected the 0th index, which is again a dictionary, so we accessed the specified key(dealID) and then print it.

###### Hope that helps

Comment: The `get` method will avoid the runtime error. It will print as `None`. In your case if key is not found will throw error

Comment: Yea, I agree @codeholic24 but I think he is trying to access the API so that he would be having an idea if the field exists or not. 
But yea, your solution is more accurate for sure.

Comment: @RAO.exec  Thank you for the justification cool